# Extract value between "[ and ]" using shell script

Tags: regex, bash, shell

Extract value between "[ and ]" using shell script

```
"[""sometext1"", ""sometext2"", ""sometext3""]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the first '['

```
echo '"[""sometext1"", ""sometext2"", ""sometext3""]"'|
   sed -r 's/"\[(.*)]"/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '"[""sometext1"", ""sometext2"", ""sometext3""]"'|cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
$ echo '"[""sometext1"", ""sometext2"", ""sometext3""]"'
"[""sometext1"", ""sometext2"", ""sometext3""]"

$ echo '"[""sometext1"", ""sometext2"", ""sometext3""]"' | perl -ne ' m/\[(.*)\]/ and print $1 '
""sometext1"", ""sometext2"", ""sometext3""
$
```